# Sonata Admin - assign permissions to roles

Tags: symfony, acl, sonata-admin, sonata, symfony-2.8

I have lack of knowledge how Symfony ACL works, especially using Sonata...

Sonata has some permissions like:

> LIST - view the list of objects
>
> VIEW - view the detail of one object
>
> CREATE - create a new object
>
> EDIT - update an existing object
>
> DELETE - delete an existing object
>
> EXPORT - (for the native Sonata export links)
>
> ALL- grants LIST, VIEW, CREATE, EDIT, DELETE and EXPORT

I also assigned my own created permissions for my own custom actions:

```
protected $accessMapping = array(
    'VERIFY' => 'EDIT',
    'UNVALIDATE' => 'EDIT',
    'CLOSE' => 'EDIT'
);
```

As I understand I just need to grant user `EDIT` permission to be able to `VERIFY`, `UNVALIDATE` and `CLOSE`.

Admin users can have 3 roles:

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

Now depending on a role user should be able to have certain permissions.

E.g. `ROLE_ADMIN` should have `LIST, VIEW, EDIT, EXPORT` and `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` should be granted `ALL`.

How could I manage it?

**P.S.** I am NOT using `SonataUserBundle`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i usually do it just use SecurityVoters

http://www.branchbit.be/blog/using-custom-voters-in-sonata-admin

This gives you a simple way of checking roles, permissions, and object properties, and decide if a specific action, is allowed on a specififc object,   by a specific user.

Comment: Such a nice example given. Thanks!

Comment: Link is broken. Do we have a new location for this?

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20180907145602/http://www.branchbit.be/blog/using-custom-voters-in-sonata-admin
as suggested edit queue is full I post the archive link as a comment